# wildcard deal with www as a subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2

i am using wildcard with apache

my APACHE CONFIG:

```
ServerAlias *.staronece1.com
DocumentRoot /staronece1/domains
```

my named file

```
$ttl 38400
staronece1.com.      IN      SOA     staronece1.com. email.yahoo.com. (
                        1334838782
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
staronece1.com.      IN      NS      staronece1.com.
staronece1.com.      IN      A       95.19.203.21
www.staronece1.com.  IN      A       95.19.203.21
server.staronece1.com. IN     A      95.19.203.21
mail.staronece1.com. IN      A       95.19.203.21
ns1.staronece1.com.  IN      A       95.19.203.21
ns2.staronece1.com.  IN      A       95.19.203.21
staronece1.com.      IN      NS      ns1.staronece1.com.
staronece1.com.      IN      NS      ns2.staronece1.com.
staronece1.com.      IN      MX      10 mail.staronece1.com.
* 14400 IN A 95.19.203.21
*.staronece1.com IN A 95.19.203.21
```

my php test file

```
/staronece1/domains/index.php



<?php

    function getBname(){
        $bname=explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],2);
        return $bname[0];
    }

    echo 'SubDomain is :'.getBname();
?>
```

if i go to `something.staronece1.com`

i get this result `SubDomain is : something`

No the problem is

```
if i go to www.staronece1.com
```

i should get empty result, because www is not a sub domain

but i get this result

```
SubDomain is : www
```

And if i go to `www.something.staronece1.com`

i get firefox error message ( site not found )

How to fix this problem??

i think the solution is: added record for www in named file

Thanks

Comment: `www` is *most definitely* a subdomain.

Comment: @Miles, How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

As Miles commented, `www` is a regular subdomain that is no different to `something`. It's very misleading in that sense, and it's not your fault that you have them confused.

For one, the DNS zones are irrelevant: `www.staronece1.com` must resolve to something, or the website won't work at all, so leave that alone.

If you really want this behaviour, you need a separate `ServerAlias www.staronece1.com` *before* your current wildcarded `ServerAlias`.

> Name-based virtual hosts for the best-matching set of s
>   are processed in the order they appear in the configuration. The first
>   matching ServerName or ServerAlias is used, with no different
>   precedence for wildcards (nor for ServerName vs. ServerAlias).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand what the problem is.  The server is acting as it is supposed to.
If the problem is that www.something.staronece1.com is not working, then add a dns record for www.something.staronece1.com and add another serveralias line to your httpd.conf:

```
ServerAlias *.*.staronece1.com
```

ideally, add it below the other ServerAlias lines.